# Computing values based on multiple fields using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently attempting to compute the value of multiple fields using Angular JS (keep in mind, never used Angular before, and thought it would be good for this problem I'm attempting to solve).

So, I have a page with multiple products. Each product has an associated ID, price, upc, etc. The idea is, you select a quantity and the total will be calculated for you as you go. Hence, I thought using the Angular data-binding technique would work well for this.

Here's what I have thus far...

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Multiple products – Total calculation</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" ng-app="wholesaleApp" ng-controller="ItemListController">

    <div data-alert class="alert-box success">
      <b>Total:</b>
      <input type="text" id="txtTotalFx" ng-value="total()" />
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12">
          <p>
            Item: <strong>51001</strong>
            <br/> Size: <strong>60 caps</strong>
            <br/> UPC: <strong>759160-51001-9</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/> Price: <strong>$12.00</strong> ea.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="small-8 large-8 product" data-item-id="51001">
          <input id="product_51001" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="51001/" />
          <input id="product_51001" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="759160-51001-9/" />
          <input id="product_51001" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="12.00/" ng-model='price.51001' />
          <input id="product_51001" type="text" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" name="product[]" value="" ng-model='qty.51001' />
          <input id="product_51001" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="," />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12">
          <p>
            Item: <strong>51002</strong>
            <br/> Size: <strong>120 caps</strong>
            <br/> UPC: <strong>759160-51002-6</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/> Price: <strong>$21.00</strong> ea.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="small-8 large-8 product" data-item-id="51002">
          <input id="product_51002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="51002/" />
          <input id="product_51002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="759160-51002-6/" />
          <input id="product_51002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="21.00/" ng-model='price.51002' />
          <input id="product_51002" type="text" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" name="product[]" value="" ng-model='qty.51002' />
          <input id="product_51002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="," />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12">
          <p>
            Item: <strong>59901</strong>
            <br/> Size: <strong>60 caps</strong>
            <br/> UPC: <strong>759160-59901-4</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/> Price: <strong>$12.50</strong> ea.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="small-8 large-8 product" data-item-id="59901">
          <input id="product_59901" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="59901/" />
          <input id="product_59901" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="759160-59901-4/" />
          <input id="product_59901" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="More Milk Special Blend Capsules/" />
          <input id="product_59901" type="text" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" name="product[]" value="" ng-model='qty.59901' />
          <input id="product_59901" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="," />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12">
          <p>
            Item: <strong>58002</strong>
            <br/> Size: <strong>2oz.</strong>
            <br/> UPC: <strong>759160-58002-9</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/> Price: <strong>$10.00</strong> ea.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="small-8 large-8 product" data-item-id="58002">
          <input id="product_58002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="58002/" />
          <input id="product_58002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="759160-58002-9/" />
          <input id="product_58002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="10.00/" ng-model='price.58002' />
          <input id="product_58002" type="text" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" name="product[]" value="" ng-model='qty.58002' />
          <input id="product_58002" type="hidden" name="product[]" value="," />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
function isNumber(b) {
  if (b) {
    var a = (b.which) ? b.which : b.keyCode;
    if ((a < 48 || a > 57) && (a < 96 || a > 105) && (a < 37 || a > 40) && a != 8 && a != 46) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var products = [];

  $(".product").each(function() {
    products.push($(this).data("item-id"));
  });

  var app = angular.module('wholesaleApp', []);

  app.controller('ItemListController', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = function() {
      var total = 0;
      console.log("entered total function...");

      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var qty = "price." + products[i];
        var price = "qty." + products[i];
        console.log("qty: " + qty + ", price: " + price + "\n");
        total += ($scope.price * $scope.qty) || 0;
        console.log("total: " + total + "\n")
      }
      return total || 0;
    };

  });
})(window.angular);
```

And, Plunker setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/tBhm37E0gaWjwC5cIzdT?p=preview

Comment: What is the actual issue that you're running into?

Comment: Nothing happens to the total, the `ng-value="total()"` portion. Also, have some console.log's in there to try and see what's going on and it doesn't even look like the `$scope.total = function()` is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is really working against angular.  You'd be much better off defining the items as javascript objects, and using that to build the html, rather than the other way around:

HTML:

```
<div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="small-12 large-12">
      <p>
        Item: <strong>{{item.id}}</strong>
        <br/> Size: <strong>{{item.size}}</strong>
        <br/> UPC: <strong>{{item.upc}}</strong>
        <br/>
        <br/> Price: <strong>{{item.price | currency}}</strong> ea.
        <br><label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model="item.quantity"/>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.items = [{
  id: 510001,
  size: '60 caps',
  upc: '759160-51001-9',
  price: 12,
  quantity: 0
}, {
  id: 51002,
  size: '120 caps',
  upc: '759160-51002-6 ',
  price: 21,
  quantity: 0
}, {
  id: 59901,
  size: '60 caps',
  upc: '759160-59901-4',
  price: 12.50,
  quantity: 0
}, {
  id: 58002,
  size: '2oz',
  upc: '759160-58002-9 ',
  price: 10,
  quantity: 0
}, ];
$scope.total = function() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    total += $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
  };
  return total;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8vSlHnvEkIy5b3wvIXRW?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @dave, but unfortunately the document is rendered via PHP. So don't think your solution will work. I'll see if I can modify further to get it working with the pre-rendered HTML.

Comment: Do you not have access to the php?

Comment: I suppose so, but have a decent amount of logic in there, and multiple loops. But, looking at it further might not be as hard as I initially thought to have it simply build the javascript objects as apposed to outputting the html. Will give it a go and come back to mark as the answer if successful ;)

Comment: Ok, managed to wrap the PHP up to output the various products/categories as JS objects, then plug that into Angular, basically using what you posted above. Works great! Thanks!!